# My CR karma raised about 6000 points, what happened?

Tags: discussion, reputation

My karma in Code Review was two days ago around 16400+. Now it is 22700+. What happened here? I received my 8th golden badge; might it be responsible for that? Also, there is no any indication from which answers or questions those points came.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Upvotes on questions used to be worth 5 reputation points (what you call karma). They recently (Wednesday 13th of November) increased this to 10 points, doubling the amount of reputation you get for a question upvote. Retroactively, so it counts for every upvote you ever got on a question (taking into account things like reputation caps per day (200) and all, it won't be double but at least a heck of a lot higher).

You have asked 354 questions on Code Review. I'm not going to do the math for you, but yes, I'd expect you to gain a couple of thousand rep from this move.

Blog post by SE which attempts to explain it:

- [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

Relevant Meta.StackExchange questions if you're looking for extra information:

- [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843/269301)
- [Regarding the recalc in question rep increase what happens due to the cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338119/269301)
- [Reputation recalculation didn't retroactively award Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338371/269301)
- [Has the penalty for having your question down voted also increased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338162/269301)

Comment: Also see related discussions on Meta Stack Overflow (disclaimer: self-promotional): [Announcement: Upvotes on questions will now be worth the same as upvotes on answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers), and [detailed background information and motivations for the change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248). The Code Review community is welcome to chime in on MSO, as well, if they'd like.

Comment: @CodyGray Don't think it's self-promotion if it's on Meta, as you don't gain rep points.